# how can I embed server codes in sharepoint pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint site with a lot of pages. we create pages using SharePoint wizard not in VS. I need to add  in one page and use a server code to read from session and write in this label.

After I open a page in VS I only see some code in comments. 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Visual webpart and add it on page. or use delegate control with user control.